# xamarin UITest - push notifications blocks automation

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.uitest

I'm running my UITests in appcenter but now we get a push notifications from the system and it blocks the automation. Is there a way to tap this notification so that it will accept those notifications or in worst case just that the notification is not prompted or discarded?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

System notifications cannot be accepted on iOS. We faced this issue when dealing with App Rating dialogs. What you can do is, create a unique UITest build configuration and add UITest under define symbols for that config. In this config, we will disable Push Notifications as shown:

```
#if UITest
// Do nothing
#else
// Push notifications activation 
// code goes here
#endif
```

You can do this at the point where the Push Notifications feature is enabled.
Then you always use that UITest configuration for running your UI Tests.

Comment: Hi Saamer, thanks. This seems not a solution (if there is one) but it can indeed help us further!